# Xcode 4.3 Breakpoint Logging object descriptions

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4.3, lldb

I'd like to move from NSLogging all over the place to using breakpoints for logging where the performance hit doesn't preclude it.

I know I can just `po` an object with a *Debugger Command* action, and I know I can just log any string by choosign the *Log Message* action.

And I think I should be able to combine both by choosing *Log Message* and entering something like `SomeText giving context for object description: @(const char *)[[anObject description] UTF8String]@`. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work, and always gives me what I assume to be the pointer to the description string.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's kinda tricky but I think that this will work. Set the breakpoint **Action** as a debugger command. Then use this text as the action:

```
po (NSString *) [@"Some text describing: " stringByAppendingString:(NSString *)[anObject description]]
```

You must always be very careful to cast return types when working in the debugger. Both with GDB and LLDB.

I like your idea of using breakpoints to avoid the performance hit, but this also means that your logs will only be printed when connected to a debugger. While NSLogs will buffer their output to the system log, viewable from the Organizer (Devices) in Xcode.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like a workable solution (even though it doesn't *directly* answer what happened to Logging actions). Actually, in my experience breakpoint logging is much slower than using NSLog, but sometimes, I don't want to spray NSLogs all over my source.

Comment: Perhaps there is something more than I can answer? I would expect the result of the expression that you put in your post to just be a pointer. Does the code I posted help you achieve the same goal and you're looking for a different way to accomplish it?

Comment: I've awarded you the bounty, because it fixes the practical problem I've had with breakpoint logging. I thought the expression in my question would print a string, not just the pointer to the string.

Answer (score 1):

***(Edit: I missed the question's point and it's not an answer)***

I think it's best to use [`DebugLog`](http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2009/03/23/114/). It's a *macro*, and you can disable it easily (it's on when you `def`-ine `DEBUG` in your debug builds and is off when you don't `define` it). So, there's no performance degradation (quite the contrary).

Simply replace

```
NSLog(@"Hello, World!");
```

with

```
DebugLog(@"Hello, World!");
```

And instead of

```
19/4/12 8:55:52.949 PM Dictionary: Hello, World!
```

You'll get:

```
BetterDictionary.m:737 Hello, World!
```

*(it shows which file and even which line has logged it)*

Which is infinitely more interesting. `undefine` DEBUG for your production build and `DebugLog` won't be called *at all*.

And don't forget to `#import 'DebugLog.h'`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: @fzwo Yes, I understood immediately after submitting the answer that I've completely missed the question's point and was about to delete it that you commented... I'll leave it here however because it might be new to others who might view it.